# Not able to use console.log from any of the application on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image]Google chrome not showing logs for `console.log()` in my js codes. Not even from jsfiddle. Not from anywhere.

I have disabled all the extensions i am using on it.
i have also relaunch the chrome.
But the problem is not getting solved.

I am not able to find what is the issue. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the output? You need to open your developers console (Tools -> Developer Tools) and switch to the 'console' tab to see console messages.

Comment: Please provides us with some code to see if the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Or better: a screenshot

Comment: u can see console.log() not working from chrome.. from screenshot

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification, can you confirm that the same actions taken in a different browser give the expected result? When I open the console at jsfiddle, I get a couple of errors, yet your screenshot doesn't show any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and it turned out I had selected that only "Errors" should be shown. If you look at the bottom of the developer tools, you have "Errors" selected. If you select "All" instead, it should hopefully work.